# What is the '__IO' directive in GCC?

Tags: gcc, embedded

I am working on an embedded device, and there is some code that was originally compiled using the IAR compiler.

I am trying to recompile said code using the GCC compiler.

There is a particular statement: `typedef __IO` , which simply doesn't get compiled ("Unrecognized symbol error").

Could anyone suggest how I could get this statement to compile properly?

Comment: `#define     __IO    volatile` or even just `#define     __IO`

Comment: @Eddy_Em:  Post answers as answers not as comments.

Comment: If it is an unrecognised symbol how do you know it is a typedef!? (its not).  Some examples of the code you are referring to might be useful.

Comment: "how do you know it is a typedef!?" I had same trouble and found it by google.

Comment: @Eddy_Em: You missed my point; since it is not *defined* (i.e. *"Unrecognized symbol error"*), it is by definition not a typedef. When defined, it is not a type in any case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it is not recognised it will be because an appropriate system header containing the definition has not been included.

It will be defined in the chip support header file provided with the toolchain.  It is *type qualifier*, or rather a macro (`#define`) that will expand to a type qualifier. It is used for example as follows:

```
__IO uint8_t CSSR;
```

Here `uint8_t` is the type, so __IO cannot in fact be a `typedef` because it is not used where a type is valid.  The __IO macro  expands to whatever the particular compiler requires to ensure correct I/O access and addressing.  In the typical case where I/O is memory mapped, it will simply expand to `volatile` since all I/O should be declared volatile to ensure explicit accesses are not optimised out.

If you want to be sure, download a demo version of the IAR tools and take a look in the header files at how it is defined for your particular architecture.  Otherwise you might just use `#define __IO volatile`

Answer (score 8):

_IO meaning volatile as per in C language...which will not optimize the code and in which value stated for the variable using _IO will be unpredictable or will be changing without knowledge of compiler and user

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but in case someone wants to know this for ARM Microcontrollers, you can see that the definition is available in the CMSIS library. For example, `__IO` is defined as follows for cortex-m4:

```
#define     __IO    volatile             /*!< Defines 'read / write' permissions */
```

The full block is copy pasted below ([Source](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/core_cm4.h#L265)):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #define   __I     volatile             /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions */
#else
  #define   __I     volatile const       /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions */
#endif
#define     __O     volatile             /*!< Defines 'write only' permissions */
#define     __IO    volatile             /*!< Defines 'read / write' permissions */

/* following defines should be used for structure members */
#define     __IM     volatile const      /*! Defines 'read only' structure member permissions */
#define     __OM     volatile            /*! Defines 'write only' structure member permissions */
#define     __IOM    volatile            /*! Defines 'read / write' structure member permissions */
```

Comment: So, why not just use `volatile`?

Comment: Clarity in context I guess. You can always get around without using pre-processor directives, but for microcontrollers saying it's an `IO` or `I` probably gives more clarity to the developers.